# get the first, the second, the third element of collection

Tags: laravel, collections

I have a collection like that:

```
Collection {#750 ▼
  #items: array:18 [▼
    18 => User {#691 ▶}
    19 => User {#696 ▶}
    20 => User {#701 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Where 18, 19, 20 should vary

I tried to call with

```
 $collection->get(0);
 $collection->get(1);
 $collection->get(2);
```

But obviously, it doesn't work

I found a workaround with shift, that return first element and remove it from the collection,

```
 $el1 = $collection->shift();
 $el2 = $collection->shift();
 $el3 = $collection->shift();
```

But in this case, my original collection is destroyed.

Any idea how I should do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`values()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-values) as:

```
$collection = $collection->values();
```

then you can use it as:

```
 $collection->get(0);
 $collection->get(1);
 $collection->get(2);
```

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro, how is this answer better than exactly the same answer with exactly the same code, posted by Joseph Silber 2 minutes earlier?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I obtain my list from a chunk, so make a slice after that is not so nice. values is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro, I'm talking about Joseph Silber answer, not mine.

Comment: ooo. values() was just edited. First answer where foreach

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro, no, Joseph gave you 2 ways to do it. Second part was exactly the same as Amit's. Click "edited X mins ago" link and you will see original answer.

Comment: yep, you're right. I guess I just saw the first way to do it

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`slice()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-slice) method:

```
$collection->slice(0, 3)
```

> The slice method returns a slice of the collection starting at the given index. If you would like to limit the size of the returned slice, pass the desired size as the second argument.

Answer (score 3):

You can either loop over them:

```php
foreach ($collection as $element) {
    // use $element
}
```

Or you can reset the keys to be sequentially indexed:

```php
$collection = $collection->values();

$element1 = $collection->get(0);
$element2 = $collection->get(1);
$element3 = $collection->get(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can access thoes values. For example, you can get keys by calling:

`$keys = $collection->keys()`

Then call by the ordered keys you wanted:

`if (isset($keys[0])) $collection->get($keys[0]);`